# BadImageFormatException When Calling .dll Built from C++ Project In NET Core

Tags: c#, c++, .net, .net-core, interop

I have two preexisting projects (C++, C# NET 4.5.2) where the C# projects calls into the C++ project.  This worked perfectly until I ported the NET 4.5.2 project to NET Core.  Now I get a BadImageFormatException when trying to access the assembly built from the C++ project.  Is it possible to call this assembly from a NET Core assembly?

```
public static string CallCPlusPlusConvert(string inputFileName)
{
    if (inputFileName == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inputFileName)); };

    return SafeNativeMethods.Convert(inputFileName);
}

internal class SafeNativeMethods
{
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
    [DllImport("CPlusPlusProject", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    internal static extern string Convert([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)][In]string filePath);
}
```

Comment: Is 'Convert' a type of reserved word in NET Core perhaps?

Comment: The original name of the method is not Convert.  There is a suffix that I removed that gives away what project the method belongs to.

Comment: Have you tried using StringBuilder as the types rather than string?  In the DLL call?

Answer (score 2):

See here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7137bfe.aspx

Check that the dll isn't specifically for an architecture other than what you're running as. Check what you complied the C++ dll as

i.e. Don't use a 64-bit dll in a 32-bit application and vice versa

EDIT: I also see that you tagged this as ASP.NET. If you're running this in IIS and get this issue then you can try to change the **Enable 32-bit Applications** option in the Advanced settings for the app pool assigned to the project

Comment: This is what I expect from a BadImageFormatException but the project is built from a script which is using the same MSBuild command as before to build the projects.

Comment: Perhaps MSBuild is targeting a different .NET version than it should. Check the details of the file and see if it's not later than 4.5.2

Comment: This is the basic answer for mixing x86/x64 libraries as OP is already aware of obviously. The problem arises when porting to netcore/standard. Since there are no executables, it is launched by first `dotnet` found in the `PATH`, which is not matching the project architecture. This is supposed to be fixed in 3.0.