# Loading a native library with .Net Core errors

Tags: c#, c++, .net-core, native

> This is probably gonna get flagged as duplicate of [BadImageFormatException When Calling .dll Built from C++ Project In NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46820197), but the original didn't help me at all and it had no solution

For the last 2 hours I've tried to get C# (.NET Core) and a C++ native dll to work together, but it didn't work. It always gives a `BadImageFormat` Exception.

I made sure that both, the C# appilcation and the C++ dll are compiled as 64-bit. I tried 2 different compilers for the c++ library, MinGW64 and the compiler that Visual Studio uses (I have no clue which compiler Visual Studio uses).

I tried the same on Linux using g++, which for some reasons worked.

Source code I used for C#:

```
[DllImport(@"libuntitled_test.dll", EntryPoint = "hello")]
static extern void Hello();

[DllImport(@"libuntitled_test.dll", EntryPoint = "hello2")]
static extern void Hello2();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Hello2();
    Console.ReadLine();
    Hello();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And thats the c++ one (MinGW)

```
// libary.cpp
#include "library.h"

#include <iostream>

EXTERN void hello() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
}

EXTERN int hello2() {
    return 7098;
}
```

also the header file

```
//libary.h
#include <iostream>

#define EXTERN extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

EXTERN void hello();

EXTERN int hello2();
```

and the cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(untitled_test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -m64)

add_library(untitled_test SHARED library.cpp library.h)
```